# Default parameters swift

Tags: swift, default-value, optional-parameters

For my default parameters should I write

```
func myFunc(optionA: Int? = 0)
```

or

```
func myFunc(optionA: Int! = 0)
```

Which is more advisable and/or more importantly which is used more in production? What happens if I use `Int!` instead of `Int?`? Can I still pass either an `Int`, `nil`, or no parameter whilst not having to unwrap the parameter when accessed? Is doing so considered lazy programming and may present potential memory insecurities?

Comment: 0 is not nil. It's not clear what your question here is. What do you expect the benefit from the `Int!` case to be? Why isn't this just `Int` if it has a default?

Comment: @RobNapier What I want to achieve is that if I do not supply a value or `nil` is supplied for the parameter its default value becomes 0. I edited my question to improve its clarity

Comment: If depends on the context. But in most of the cases the best choice for an `Int` parameter is a non-optional.

Comment: @vadian could you explain a bit more why `Int` parameters should be non-optional? I am simply trying to achieve method overloading

Comment: Swift's strong type concept suggests to avoid optionals as much as possible. Non-optional types can never cause the app to crash at runtime. The *no value* case of an `Int` can be represented by 0, -1 (if the valid integers are positive) or `NSNotFound` which is the same as `Int.max`. So you have three options. If none of them is reasonable then use an optional.

Comment: Also in general having optional parameters to a function (especially if it's the *only* parameter!) should be avoided wherever possible. It just makes the function's *function* much more ambiguous for cases when you come to pass in `nil` for a parameter. What should it do in that case? (Think about your code as if you know nothing about the internal implementation)

Comment: @vadian well then my question is what the heck is the point of optionals? For amateur programmers? Is there ever a case in which optionals are useful? I feel like when designing an API you might want the option to pass `nil` or omit a parameter. I mean the Apple API has countless functions with `nil` permitted parameter values. I apologize if my questions seem trivial. I honestly want to know the production coding practices

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath Optionals *definitely* have their use, and are really useful when used correctly. In general, they make more sense for reference types than value types – as most value types have an equivalent of `nil`. For example `Int` has `0`, `String` has `""`, `Array` has `[]` etc. Reference types on the other hand make more sense, as `nil` means there's no reference. Optionals can also be used as return values from functions if those processes have an element of 'fail-ability'. Also bear in mind that most Apple APIs are written in obj-c, where `nil` is assignable to any object type.

Comment: I totally agree with @originaluser2's explanation

Comment: @originaluser2 Well what do I do about private class properties? Do I initialize them inline, or do I make them optional and initialize their values in the proper constructors?

Comment: @vadian No, no, no don't avoid optionals. Using 0, -1 or some other sentinel as you suggest is a much inferior solution. With optionals, the type system enforces the unwrapping, so you can be certain that the value you're dealing with is real data, not just some crap you stuck in there as a sentinel. With sentinels, it's really easy to forget a check, and use the sentinel value as if it were data. Optionals are an elegant syntax for expressing that a value is dangerous (because it could be nil, which is just as bad as it being a sentinel) and should be treated appropriately.

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath It completely depends on their purpose. In general, you should always prefer a property with a default value, or a lazy property (if it depends on an instance state) over an optional property. The question you should really be asking yourself is "Does being `nil` say something *meaningful* about this property's value – or am I just using it to work around something else?" If it doesn't make sense for a value to ever be `nil` – then it should definitely be non-optional.

Comment: @AMomchilov forgetting a check for a particular sentinel is as dangerous as forgetting an optional binding. Both is the fault of the programmer not of the compiler. As I mentioned in my first comment, it depends on the context. And in terms of real life / real data most of the optional integers or even an optional boolean are absurd.

Comment: @vadian You can't forget an optional binding. That's the whole point, the type system enforces it.

Comment: @AMomchilov The unchallenged #1 Swift question on SO is *Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value* ;-)

Comment: @vadian, yes, people are lazy and abuse the force unwrap operator. This completely waives the benefits of optionals.

Comment: @AMomchilov Amateurish programmers might be supposed to be protected by the compiler. Everybody else is supposed to know what's he's / she's doing...

Comment: @vadian That's a bullshit argument, and rather elitest. Turning run-time errors like rogue sentinel values into compile-time errors is one of the main goals of modern language design. It's why generics exist. You can go ahead and use `Any` or `NSObject` everywhere, and you won't miss out on anything at all. But sooner or later, it'll bite you in the ass.

Comment: Would anyone in this discussion be willing to give me some constructive criticism on my Swift code? It would be a huge help as I aspire to use production standard practices

Comment: I'll take a peek, post a link

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath I would recommend taking a look at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), although note that in [order for a question to be on-topic there](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), you should be presenting *working* code.

Comment: @AMomchilov I have an API called NoodleKit that is not yet ready for release. You can peek at my code at this link: http://www.github.com/NoodleOfDeath/NoodleKit I truly appreciate any criticism/advice/suggestions you may for me

Comment: I would make a dictionary to map powers of 1024 to `DataSize` objects, and get rid of that switch on line 81 of `NoodleKit.swift`. Line 116 of  `BMDocumentViewController.swift` should be reworked to actually handle the case when the optionals are nil. The `∄` operator is evil lol, how are people supposed to type that? :p

Comment: https://github.com/NoodleOfDeath/NoodleKit/blob/master/NoodleKit/Class%20Extensions/NSFileManager.swift#L162 You want your happy path to have the minimal possible nesting. In this case, it's better to do a check and return out of the function early, like: `if !url.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil) { return nil; }` and then continue to the happy path after. Otherwise, every precondition you check would entail yet another level of indentation, and it wouldn't be uncommon to get 5+ layers in before any of your actual happy path code.

Comment: @AMomchilov You're right! I totally forgot about the `∄` operator. I meant to remove that. I use TextExpander, but I realize that not everyone using the API would be able to type it. Do you mind reading into some of my class extensions? Also thanks about the reduction of nesting tip

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath Let's continue in here chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111058/noodleofdeath-code-review

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0 Isn't nil. In either case, you're making `optionA` have a value of `0`, not `nil`.

The correct answer here depends on what kind of interface you want your function to have.

- If you want callers to be able to pass an `Int`, `nil` or no parameter at all, then `optionA` should be an `Int?` type.
- If you want callers to be able to pass an `Int`, no parameter at all, but NOT `nil`, then `optionA` should be an `Int` type.

Comment: What happens if I use `Int!` instead? Can I still achieve this functionality whilst not having to unwrap the parameter when accessed? Is doing so considered lazy programming and present potential memory insecurities?

Comment: I'm not near my Mac to be able to test this, but if I recall correctly: the `Int` type will prevent `nil` being passed in (via compiler type error), the `Int?` type will allow `nil` being passed in, but will require manual unwrapping, and `Int!` will allow `nil` being passed in, but will make the universe explode.

Comment: To answer your latter question: Yes, abusing the force unwrapping operator is considered lazy, and is pretty much the first example of bad Swift practices that any one mentions. Memory is still kind of safe, as force unwrapping a `nil` optional will always cause a run time error (preventing any dangerous memory operations from being possible)

Answer (score 2):

> if I do not supply a value or nil is supplied for the parameter its default value becomes 0.

This is a very strange requirement, and likely indicates a design error. However, it is trivial to implement.

```
func myFunc(optionA: Int? = nil) {
    let a = optionA ?? 0
    // ...continue to use a...
}
```

That said, this is almost certainly a broken API. It would be helpful to give a more concrete example of what problem you're solving that isn't solved by just `func myFunc(a: Int)` (which should be your strong preference unless you have a good reason for something else).